# Dovecot IMAP authentication failed

Tags: debian, dovecot, imap

Whenever I'm trying to connect to my Dovecot IMAP server, it gives me a message that the authentication was failed.
This message is from the `/var/log/mail.log` file:

```
Feb  7 15:22:17 celestine dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts in 2 secs): user=<celestine>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, TLS, session=<QsPvvtbx5AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
```

I tried connecting with the Roundcube webmail program, bit in the IMAP log it says the following:

```
[07-Feb-2014 15:22:15 -0500]: [A4F2] S: * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE AUTH=PLAIN] Dovecot ready.
[07-Feb-2014 15:22:15 -0500]: [A4F2] C: A0001 ID ("name" "Roundcube" "version" "0.9.5" "php" "5.4.4-14+deb7u7" "os" "Linux" "command" "/")
[07-Feb-2014 15:22:15 -0500]: [A4F2] S: * ID NIL
[07-Feb-2014 15:22:15 -0500]: [A4F2] S: A0001 OK ID completed.
[07-Feb-2014 15:22:15 -0500]: [A4F2] C: A0002 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN AGNlbGVzdGluZQAxMDA5OTU=
[07-Feb-2014 15:22:17 -0500]: [A4F2] S: A0002 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.
```

If I try to connect with another program, it also won't work.

I have SSL enabled so my IMAP server is running on port 993. The following is my `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`:

```
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_privileged_group = mail
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
passdb {
  driver = passwd
}

protocols = "imap"

protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = " autocreate"
}
plugin {
  autocreate = Trash
  autocreate2 = Sent
  autosubscribe = Trash
  autosubscribe2 = Sent
}

service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}

ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/localcerts/mail.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/localcerts/mail.key
```

I'm using Debian Squeeze with Postfix installed.

Comment: Is `celestine` your login and `100995` actually your password? It should be working.

Comment: That's what I thought too, I assume that the IMAP user is the same as the UNIX user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly I assume that user `celestine` (with password `100995`) is set up correctly in your system (simply check if a login is successful with no further errors / warnings).

According to your dovecot.conf, you set up your server authentication process using **Lookup databases** with ***passwd***. That's fine as User Database, but with passwd as *Password Database* you can't get the user's password on Debian, as stated in the official Dovecot documentation:

hxxp://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/Passwd :

> Most commonly used as a user database. Many systems use shadow passwords nowadays so it doesn't usually work as a password database.

You can work around this problem with

```
passdb {
  driver = shadow
}
```

Another possiblity would be using passdb with [Passwd-file](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/PasswdFile), but I recommend you set up your Dovecot authenticate system [using PAM](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/PAM).

Good luck,
Megodin

Comment: I'm now using PAM and it actually worked! I didn't know the solution to this was so easy, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that my imap server changes all entered usernames to lowercase, and thus there was no user named the name it thought I had written. I made an all lower-case user and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please check CPHulk Brute Force Protection >> History Reports and click on remove blocks and reports, it will fix this issue.