# Roundcube IMAP log -- NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed

Tags: email-server, dovecot, pam, imap, roundcube

system: Ubuntu 17.10

This is the error I am getting when trying to log in log-file 
`/var/lib/roundcube/logs/imap`:

```
[17-Apr-2018 22:03:13 -0700]: <3aedeusd> [1116] S: * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE AUTH=PLAIN] Dovecot (Ubuntu) ready.
[17-Apr-2018 22:03:13 -0700]: <3aedeusd> [1116] C: A0001 ID ("name" "Roundcube" "version" "1.3.6" "php" "7.1.16-1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1" "os" "Linux" "command" "/webmail/?_task=login")
[17-Apr-2018 22:03:13 -0700]: <3aedeusd> [1116] S: * ID ("name" "Dovecot")
[17-Apr-2018 22:03:13 -0700]: <3aedeusd> [1116] S: A0001 OK ID completed.
[17-Apr-2018 22:03:13 -0700]: <3aedeusd> [1116] C: A0002 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN ****** [57]
[17-Apr-2018 22:03:17 -0700]: <3aedeusd> [1116] S: A0002 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.
```

`/var/log/mail.log`:

```
Apr 17 22:03:17 hostname dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts in 4 secs): user=<me@domain.net>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<WGxhquKUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
```

I did not define a dovecot like as in this post [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/574044/dovecot-imap-authentication-failed), but have this
`/etx/pam.d/dovecot`:

```
#%PAM-1.0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session
```

Connection to server runs over SSL.

I am not sure if this is a Roundcube problem, or a postfix problem. For now it looks like PAM needs configuring.